# PHP call_user_func_array instance inside instance

Tags: php

```
<?php

class foo 
{
    private $callVar = false;
    private $constructorVar = false;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->constructorVar = get_class($this);
    }

    public function __call($methodName, $arguments) 
    {
        $this->callVar = get_class($this);
        call_user_func_array(array($this, $methodName), $arguments);
    }

    protected function method($params)
    {
        echo('<br>Call var: '.$this->callVar.'<br>Constructor var: '.$this->constructorVar);
    }
}

class foo_sec extends foo
{
    protected function method($params)
    {
        echo 'First call: ';
        parent::method($params);
        echo '<br> Second call: ';
        $test = new foo_trd();
        $test->method('param2');
    }
}

class foo_trd extends foo
{

}

$m = new foo_sec();
$m->method('param');

?>
```

Gives this result:

```
First call:
Call var: foo_sec
Constructor var: foo_sec
Second call:
Call var:
Constructor var: foo_trd
```

This code should return the name of the instance that is currently running, but if the instance is inside another instance, the class name is empty in second one. Is this a PHP bug or some other issue I'm missing?

In other words, the `Call var` in the second call should be `foo_trd` - not empty.

Comment: Your problem doesn't lie with call_user_func_array() but with php not calling magic function __call.

Comment: @Rahi but why? It's a completely new instance

Comment: @RyanVincent I solved it already using another approach but I was wandering why isn't this working right, cause it should

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are experiencing something interesting to do with PHP and its [inheritance visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php#language.oop5.visibility-other-objects).

In short when you are inside and instance of `Foo` you have access to the `protected` and `private` scope of all other instances that also extend `Foo`. As you are allowed to access the `protected method()` directly you will skip the call to `__call()`.

This can actually be useful when you want to make your constructor private and enforce factories.

Comment: But inside foo_sec I am creating new instance, this should be handled as it's own instance with no recollection to instance that created it.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer as this links to php documentation explaining that this is normal php behaviour

Comment: As both instances inherit a common parent they are "related". There is a nice way to implement the factory pattern doing this by making the `__construct` method protected/private and enforcing the usage of a `public static create()` (or similar) function to construct it. But yeah, its an interesting thing in PHP.